# Export to JSX for After Effects no longer working on 2.91

Tags: export, compositing-nodes

I've installed the After Effects JSX export add-on, and it was working fine in 2.90, but with 2.91, it says "Upgrade to 2.8x required" and it doesn't give me the option to export anymore.

As I do a lot of 3D to 2D workflow, that plug-in was very vital.

Is there any plans to update the plug-in or is there an alternative method?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You are most likely trying to install the 2.7x version of the add-on. Try to install the 2.8x version if there is any.

Comment: You were absolutely right. It's working now. Thanks! I hope they will add this officially so that I don't have to hunt for it.